# Building Tor locally from src on raspberry pi

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspbian

After wondering why Tor would download but would not run on my raspberry pi, I found this question.
[How To Run Tor On Raspberry Pi](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/242/how-to-run-tor-on-raspbian-on-the-raspberry-pi). The answer says:

> Solution If you want to run newer Tor versions than are available from
>   the Raspbian folks, you will have to build them yourself.
>
> You can build it from the source tarball like a lot of other
>   Unix/Linux software and install it locally.

But I cant find any tutorials on how to do this. Can anyone tell me how I install tor from the source locally? Thanks!

Comment: Which Raspberry Pi do you have? If you are running the Raspberry Pi Model 2 or newer, you can use the official Debian repository. You only need to build from source if you are using the older Arm6 model.

Answer (score 1):

No problem! Doing it myself regulary! You need a gcc and g++ and the next libraries, *compiled in the order of listing here* :

- [Zlib](http://zlib.net/). You need it to compile OpenSSL with compression support
- [OpenSSL](https://www.openssl.org/source/). Take a stable source if you're not PRO with source building
- [Libevent](http://libevent.org/). Take a 2.0 current version and go on

In configure I strongly recommend you to install in a global system prefix - for your own good - I'm doing it like this :

```
./configure --prefix=/usr --localstatedir=/var --sysconfdir=/etc
```

and in OpenSSL **don't forget to set your openssldir to /etc/ssl**

after building + configuring + **testing/checking** and installing properly working packages specified above - just run `ldconfig` with no arguments from a root user - and build Tor! Feel free to ask further questions! And take a look at my [linux-builder](https://github.com/netsafe/linux-builder/) project, it's related to exactly that situation, but it's a bit outdated ;)